# Multidimensional associative arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to store all post data from html form in array. Until now I was storing data in map:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> > postFields;
```

The problem is when I have array in html form:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='add[]' value='1' >
<input type='checkbox' name='add[]' value='2' >
```

Array should looks like this:

```
fieldName => "value"
fieldName2 => "value2"
add => 1
       2
```

Is there any elastic solution for these arrays ? What if I'll want to store deeper array ?
How to solve this ?